# How much durability does each tier of tool have?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have the next tier of tools unlocked above flimsy, but upgrading tools costs an iron nugget, which I don't have a whole lot of, so I want to be sure that it's worth the upgrade. How much durability does the next tier of tools have vs the flimsy tier?

Comment: Flimsy has 10 uses for bugs / fish. I think it varies per tool, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

From the wiki on [animalcrossing.fandom.com](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Tools_(New_Horizons)), I've listed the durability per tool below. Unfortunately, not every tool durability has been determined here. If anyone has more data, please feel free to comment or edit my answer.

A 'use' is a successful hit on an object - catching a bug, hitting a tree (whether it yields resources or not). It is not (yet) clear whether missing a swing (hitting air) will degrade the durability. It should also be noted that durability degrades on other islands - as the game warns you when flying to another island.

**Fishing Rods**

- Flimsy: 10 uses
- Regular: 30 uses
- Golden: ??

**Nets**

- Flimsy: 10 uses
- Regular: 30 uses
- Golden: ??

**Shovels**

- Flimsy: 25 uses? (needs confirmation)
- Shovel: 100 uses? (needs confirmation)
- Golden: 200 uses
- Outdoorsy: ??

**Axes**

- Flimsy: 40 uses
- Stone: 100 uses
- Golden: 200 uses
- Axe (the one used for chopping down trees): 100 uses

**Watering cans**

- Flimsy: 20 uses
- Regular: 100 uses? (needs confirmation)
- Golden: ??
- Colorful: ??
- Elephant: ??

**Slingshots**

- Regular: 20 uses
- Golden: ??
- Outdoorsy: ??
- Colorful: ??

**Misc**

- Ladder: unlimited
- Vaulting pole: unlimited
- Wands: unlimited

Source(s): [animalcrossing.fandom.com](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Tools_(New_Horizons))

Comment: Is it confirmed that a use = successful hit with the tool? i.e a successfully caught fish/bug, a hit on a balloon

Comment: I know for sure that an unsuccessful hit counts as a use for axes (that is, hitting a rock and not getting any resources out of it)

Comment: What about not hitting anything? For example, swinging at a rock, but standing too far away so just 'swing at the air'?

Answer (score 1):

According to my own testing...

### Shovel:

- **Flimsy**: 40 hits
- **Regular**: 100 hits

### Axe:

- **Flimsy**: 30 hits
- **Stone**: 100 hits
- **Regular (can cut down trees)**: 100 hits

I have yet to get data on fishing poles and bug nets, or any gold variants of any tools (just not there yet!).